# django and s3 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I am trying to update files to s3 and it is failing.

I installed `django-storages` and `boto`.

this my code:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "xyxyxyx"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "yxyxy+yxx+yxyx"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "mysite"
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mysite.media'
```

and model defined as usual:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    customimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='customimg/')
```

I tried to upload a file from django admin and after a while, the error came:

```
[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

am I missing something?

how can I set s3 regions in settings if it is depending on the region?

Comment: Can you add the code that's connecting with your S3 bucket? For what it's worth, I've used S3 with Django before and never had to mess with any region settings.

Comment: You have the bucket name in there twice... do the credentials have the right to create buckets? check you aws s3 policy for the credentials...